# How to post JSON but get XML response using Retrofit?

Tags: android, xml, json, retrofit

I have a particular webservice that expects a JSON as post, and will spit back an XML. I'm using Retrofit for all my network calls. Here is how I set the Retrofit adapter with the XML converter:

```
mRestAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(getBaseUrl())
                    .setConverter(new SimpleXMLConverter())
                    .build();
```

As you can see, I'm not using the Gson converter. How can I manage to post any JSON? Thanks!

Comment: retrofit2 now supports setting multiple converter. You can now use .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).addConverterFactory(SimpleXMLConverterFactory.create())

Comment: Re: Fabian - How can I set the response format(xml or json) in the service interface if it can be different for all methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create custom `Converter`. That will use different converters for serialization and deserialization.

```
public class MixedConverter implements Converter {
      private Converter mSerializer;
      private Converter mDeserializer;

    public MixedConverter(Converter serializer, Converter deserializer) {
        mSerializer = serializer;
        mDeserializer = deserializer;
    }


    @Override
    public Object fromBody(TypedInput body, Type type) throws ConversionException {
        return mDeserializer.fromBody(body, type);
    }

    @Override
    public TypedOutput toBody(Object object) {
        return mSerializer.toBody(object);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
.setConverter(new MixedConverter(new SimpleXMLConverter(), new GsonConverter(gson)));
```

Comment: Since you want to post JSON, the order needs to be reversed:

.setConverter(new MixedConverter(new GsonConverter(gson), new SimpleXMLConverter()))