# How to post JSON but get XML response using Retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit2

From server send Json, but Retrofit2 response is xml.

I've found a solution in this link.
[retrofit solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436266/how-to-post-json-but-get-xml-response-using-retrofit)

But this solution is retroft not retrofit2.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom converter with both JSON and XML converters as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27743259/5137352) of the question that you referenced in the question. Then use that converter to create `Retrofit` instance.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(new MixedConverter(new SimpleXMLConverter(), GsonConverterFactory.create()))
        .build();
ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [POJO Generator Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8113-pojo-generator) for custom converter **`response`** from `JSON` or `XML`, with it you can post `JSON` with `XML` **`response`**

and **usage** :

```
.setConverter(new MixedConverter(new SimpleXMLConverter(), new GsonConverter(gson)));
```

and use as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436266/how-to-post-json-but-get-xml-response-using-retrofit)